# Delphi 2009 Exception Tracking

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-2009

I've inherited a big @$$ Delphi Application that by itself are so full of problems, that I'm not sure how I will be able to track down a problem that I'm currently getting.

The application crashes and terminates abnormally, and I'm unable to establish a pattern. I've added madExcept, and that helped me  a lot getting some other problems, but when the application dies, not even madExcept is able to stop it so that I can get an exception report. I've downloaded Eurekalog as well to see if this can help me, but no luck.

Does anybody have a solution on what I can try. Any tool that will be able to help me out in tracking down the problem. SmartInspect does have some kind of solution, but I will have to change a lot of code for it to work, and unfortunately the main unit of this application sit with over 53k lines of code. (Just nasty).

Any help on what I can use to track this error will be appreciated. I need to but this "tracker" on a user machine because this application is running live at almost 2000 users.

If anybody also know why a random RICHEDIT20.DLL access violation will pop up now and again, it will be very usefull, because why it happens just baffles me completely.

Thanks
Jaques

Answer (score 0):

Last time I had to do such a task (when Eureka and mad didn't suffice), I included CodeSite (Raize) logging, so you can log initially at key points in your application. In several cycles you'll need to add more to narrow down the problem. Advantage of CodeSite is that it enables you to log to another machine, so if your application crashes the system, the logging will be secured.